# Selecting a map table of a father-son table

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, recursive-query

I have a categories table with a father-son relationship which looks something like this:

### Table name:

tblCategories

### Columns:

catID 
catFatherID - This column has a relationship to catID

What I need is to select for each category it's entire family childs (including itself) in the following way:
Original table rows:

```
| catID | catFatherID |
= = = = = = = = = = = =
|   1   | null        |
|   2   |  1          |
|   3   |  1          |
|   4   |  2          |
|   5   |  3          |
|   6   |  4          |
```

What I want to get:

```
| Category ID | Family Category ID |
= = = = = = = = = = = = = =  = = = =
| 1 | 1 | (Yes, I want it to include itself in the return family members)
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 |
```

Ask if I didn't explain something enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) would be a good match to solve this. The trick is to retain a `root` ID while executing the CTE.

#### SQL Statement

```
;WITH q AS (
  SELECT  root = catID, catID, catFatherID
  FROM    tblCategories
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  q.root, c.catID, c.catFatherID
  FROM    q 
          INNER JOIN tblCategories c ON c.catFatherID = q.catID 

)
SELECT  root, catID
FROM    q
ORDER BY
        root, catID
```

#### Test script

```
;WITH tblCategories (catID, catFatherID) AS (
  SELECT  1, NULL
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 1
  UNION ALL SELECT 4, 2
  UNION ALL SELECT 5, 3
  UNION ALL SELECT 6, 4
)
, q AS (
  SELECT  root = catID, catID, catFatherID
  FROM    tblCategories
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  q.root, c.catID, c.catFatherID
  FROM    q 
          INNER JOIN tblCategories c ON c.catFatherID = q.catID 

)
SELECT  root, catID
FROM    q
ORDER BY
        root, catID
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use recursive SQL with CTE.

```
with families(id, parent_id) as (
  select * from tblCategories where id = __initial_id__
  union all
  select t.* from tblCategories as t inner join families as f on t.catFatherID = f.id 
)
 select * from families
```

See [article at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)

Comment: you should retain the parentId and select it in the final result. In its current form, this does not return what OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH n(catId, catFatherId) AS 
   (SELECT catId, catFatherId 
    FROM tblCategories 
        UNION ALL
    SELECT n1.catId, n1.catFatherId 
    FROM tblCategories as n1, n
    WHERE n.catId = n1.catFatherId)
SELECT * FROM n
```